# Why does every component in my page appears twice?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have created a sort of First page for my project, but I don't know why it renders everything twice on my page:

here is my `First.vue` component that is used by the router as the first page:

```
<template>
    <h1>Bienvenue</h1>
    <router-view></router-view>
    <div class="routing" v-if="this.$route.path == '/'">
        <router-link to='/app'>Go to application</router-link>
        <br>
        <router-link to='/test'>Go to test</router-link>
    </div>

    
    
</template>
```

and here is what I get on the page when I `npm run serve`

[image]

Does anyone knows where it comes from?

---

**UPDATE**

When I delete the `router-view` element, the components appear once but when I click on one of the links, it changes the URL of the page but the page in itself is not showing the component.
[image]

[image]

And when I try to put everything in my `router-view`, like this:

```
<template>
    
    <router-view>
    <div class="routing" v-if="this.$route.path == '/'">
        <h1>Bienvenue</h1>
        <router-link to='/app'>Go to application</router-link>
        <br>
        <router-link to='/test'>Go to test</router-link>
    </div>
    </router-view>
    
    
</template>
```

it appears once, but like the other case, when I click on a link, it is just changing the URL and not the page.

---

Here is my `index.js` to show you how my routes are defined:

```
import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from 'vue-router'
import App from '../App.vue'
import Test from '../Views/Test.vue'
import First from '../Views/First.vue'


export const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [
        {
            path:'/',
            name: 'First',
            component: First,
        },
        {
            path:'/test',
            name: 'Test',
            component: Test
        },
        {
            path:'/app',
            name: 'App',
            component: App
        }
    ]
})
```

---

*Just to clarify what results I expect from my app:*

When I run the project, I want to launch on a page with just a header saying 'Hello' at the top of the page and two links where I can either click on 'Go to the application' or 'Go to test'.
Then, when I click on one of the links, I want to see the content of the component (so either test or the app), but I don't want to see the header and the links anymore.

Comment: Hi, Why you are using `router-view` in here? Can you share the script part of the component.

Comment: @YashMaheshwari when I delete the `router-view` element, when I click for exemple on the 'Go to test' element, it changes the URL of the page but it doesn't show the component `Test.vue`

Comment: An also the `First.vue`component doesn't have a script for now, it only contains a `template`

Comment: Can you add how you have defined your routes?

Comment: @YashMaheshwari yes I have edited my post!

Comment: Are you getting any error on console, when not using router-view and clicking the link.

Comment: @YashMaheshwari No i don't have any error message, even when I don't use router-view

Comment: your doing it wrong, <router-view></router-view> should be in `App.vue`, not in every page, its job is to render/place the current view/route component, then the path:'/app', the route shouldn't be calling App.vue

Comment: Yes, you mainly use router view in components, when dealing with child components.

Comment: I tried adding router view in my components and deleting it from the first page but when I do that, the component doesn't load, even if the URL is changing

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try this:

```
    {
        path: "/app",
        component: () => import("../App.vue"),
        name: "App"
    },
    {
        path: "/test",
        component: () => import("../Views/Test.vue"),
        name: "Test"
    },
    {
        path: "/",
        component: () => import("../Views/First.vue"),
        name: "First"
    }
```

Comment: I just tried like this, with and without the `<router-view>` but it does the same thing than before

Comment: whoops, sorry. this is not my style so... but you can check this out: https://github.com/KnowsCount/tutter/tree/master/src/router

Answer (score 0):

Update with sample code or you can refer to [live code](https://jsfiddle.net/tonytinnguyen/rksocdmt/42/)  here.

```js
// App.vue
const First = {
template: `<div class = "container" id="app">

      <h1>Hi from First</h1>

      <hr>
      <router-link to="/foo">Foo</router-link>
      <router-link to="/bar">Bar</router-link>
  </div>
`
}

const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' }
const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }

const routes = [
  {
            path:'/',
            name: 'First',
            component: First,
            default: First
        },
        {
            path:'/foo',
            name: 'Foo',
            component: Foo
        },
        {
            path:'/bar',
            name: 'Bar',
            component: Bar
        }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

```js
// main.js
<div id="app">
  <!-- route outlet -->
  <!-- component matched by the route will render here -->
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Comment: When doing that it still renders all the element twice and when I click on a link it still shows the links and the 'Hello first' title which I don't want to show

Comment: when I put $ in $mount, it gives me a `TypeError: Object(...)(...).use(...).$mount is not a function`